# How to share docker metrics with Prometheus using Ubuntu server Snap Docker Service

Tags: docker, prometheus, ubuntu-22.04, snap

I am using Ubuntu server with a Docker Service installed from the Server Setup (snap) and Prometheus running in a docker container.

#### Server:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

#### Docker

```
sudo snap services
Service                          Startup  Current   Notes
docker.dockerd                   enabled  active    -
docker.nvidia-container-toolkit  enabled  inactive  -
lxd.activate                     enabled  inactive  -
lxd.daemon                       enabled  inactive  socket-activated
lxd.user-daemon                  enabled  inactive  socket-activated
```

#### snap

```
snap    2.61.1
snapd   2.61.1
series  16
ubuntu  22.04
kernel  5.15.0-91-generic
```

#### Prometheus docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
volumes:
  prometheus_data: {}

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /home/xxxx/data/config/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'

    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

    ports:
      - "9090:9090/tcp"
```

Docker IP:

```
ip addr show docker0
    8: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
        link/ether 02:42:18:5c:09:7f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::42:18ff:fe5c:97f/64 scope link
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

### Issue

So what I want to do is get metrics for my Prometheus Server running in a docker container. I am using this documentation: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/prometheus/

In the beginning it says: **Add the following configuration:**

```
Linux: /etc/docker/daemon.json

{
  "metrics-addr": "127.0.0.1:9323"
}
```

I also tried with:

```
{
   "metrics-addr": "172.17.0.1:9323"
}
```

After some trouble I found following question / answer on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296892/snap-edit-docker-configuration

So I added the daemon.json to

```
/var/snap/docker/current/etc/docker
```

and restarted the service with:

```
sudo snap restart docker
```

after the restart I still do not get any metrics from the host. I test this using:

```
curl http://localhost:9323/metrics
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9323 after 0 ms: Connection refused
curl http://172.17.0.1:9323/metrics
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.1 port 9323 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

[image: Prometheus Target Error]

#### Docker system info

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.10.4)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.17.2)

Server:
 Containers: 20
  Running: 20
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 20
 Server Version: 20.10.24
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 2806fc1057397dbaeefbea0e4e17bddfbd388f38
 runc version:
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.15.0-91-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu Core 22
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 31.26GiB
 Name: blackholeport
 ID: AMKQ:XQSW:OPFY:ZLWE:VCVI:BKBB:NVO4:5WYJ:W6AZ:JB7M:7T4S:WXNC
 Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Username: hagbart
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

#### docker inspect prometheus

```
[
    {
        "Id": "ded87ebe4dafa575a06781beacf7e33541a37d23c1594ce0ac80041929ba5684",
        "Created": "2024-01-19T10:23:03.520072505Z",
        "Path": "/bin/prometheus",
        "Args": [
            "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 83237,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2024-01-19T13:00:24.320370241Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2024-01-19T13:00:17.400204943Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:2a72b385beafd2b3685ad337d14d23f6851f0ff335c5cd9a04c692b3eb846196",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/ded87ebe4dafa575a06781beacf7e33541a37d23c1594ce0ac80041929ba5684/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/ded87ebe4dafa575a06781beacf7e33541a37d23c1594ce0ac80041929ba5684/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/ded87ebe4dafa575a06781beacf7e33541a37d23c1594ce0ac80041929ba5684/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/containers/ded87ebe4dafa575a06781beacf7e33541a37d23c1594ce0ac80041929ba5684/ded87ebe4dafa575a06781beacf7e33541a37d23c1594ce0ac80041929ba5684-json.log",
        "Name": "/prometheus",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/home/lukas/data/config/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:rw"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "prometheus_default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "9090/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "9090"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "unless-stopped",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "private",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": [
                "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
            ],
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": null,
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "Mounts": [
                {
                    "Type": "volume",
                    "Source": "prometheus_prometheus_data",
                    "Target": "/prometheus",
                    "VolumeOptions": {}
                }
            ],
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/5656a88cbb1d0e0fd4ed939b0cdb30de86b7d2e4af2afd06d2ea33d8dd110199-init/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/0aa7d62082adf6dcde04943d937cac5dae5d0609b12ae7319421cbf63131fca3/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/59878a50f72e66a191110dadd15bf94d352cb1e0a543cf6ab0e96f210d9a16e5/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/d7dd0384e6e888b48e94d3f32bf1e504c2ed1d11526ba5caba7a6cbaa43f1304/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/8943641d04172c565f42e75963910fdf6df436bc60d3929284c657b16d831dd1/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/6c943a9276d504534ec9c66ade625447ad516058dce64053b899283aac500395/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/416d42bd54e76f8a2c78da2799ad6e6c5d2c3d78b822ed8e17ada9bdc0fc17a7/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/89ab8fa214a8141179afa2c21071e565dc841d1e0f5a69dc372d5b6514456cb0/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/d99204b78e6ddf1279d8f1b099318f921a61e9017d457955e5a53c5c2d17be8a/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/259c1d3c5a275a0c51fe499c1a8a2857427cf592eb094dea65447b591ec66058/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/721958698d3add899bd2597d3dab22267c3aaa40dc556eb7f0cdb8c564b14a74/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/c122e772ebb24d66d663577b099800060d10e1d1fda0b38e75ea73bc2fdf6273/diff:/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/b1a9df93abc1fbba6b8f3644eaf5ec9a76b8b2193ad1d934241242fb54b74cd0/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/5656a88cbb1d0e0fd4ed939b0cdb30de86b7d2e4af2afd06d2ea33d8dd110199/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/5656a88cbb1d0e0fd4ed939b0cdb30de86b7d2e4af2afd06d2ea33d8dd110199/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/overlay2/5656a88cbb1d0e0fd4ed939b0cdb30de86b7d2e4af2afd06d2ea33d8dd110199/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/lukas/data/config/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
                "Destination": "/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "prometheus_prometheus_data",
                "Source": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/prometheus_prometheus_data/_data",
                "Destination": "/prometheus",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "z",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "ded87ebe4daf",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "nobody",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "9090/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml"
            ],
            "Image": "prom/prometheus:latest",
            "Volumes": {
                "/prometheus": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/prometheus",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/bin/prometheus"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "com.docker.compose.config-hash": "f387601dc597da679d6a2290f4192863d07c16791b9d33e29a4e84eb43b2e5df",
                "com.docker.compose.container-number": "1",
                "com.docker.compose.depends_on": "",
                "com.docker.compose.image": "sha256:2a72b385beafd2b3685ad337d14d23f6851f0ff335c5cd9a04c692b3eb846196",
                "com.docker.compose.oneoff": "False",
                "com.docker.compose.project": "prometheus",
                "com.docker.compose.project.config_files": "/home/lukas/BlackholePort/docker/prometheus/docker-compose.yml",
                "com.docker.compose.project.working_dir": "/home/lukas/BlackholePort/docker/prometheus",
                "com.docker.compose.service": "prometheus",
                "com.docker.compose.version": "2.17.2",
                "maintainer": "The Prometheus Authors <prometheus-developers@googlegroups.com>"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "b882dba1196b5ba11a81cedda028552f453ed82e42cec9fc8fc767d4192571f2",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "9090/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "9090"
                    },
                    {
                        "HostIp": "::",
                        "HostPort": "9090"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/run/snap.docker/netns/b882dba1196b",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "prometheus_default": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "prometheus",
                        "prometheus",
                        "ded87ebe4daf"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "971e8873d46285b63d70fb6feeada747176a5427aa7a19127cb7e8dc8a7d8a37",
                    "EndpointID": "b67826c8e2736e5ac55ab67a8f9d67a6822dd3260a214622f65de968b0fa972e",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.32.1",
                    "IPAddress": "192.168.32.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 20,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:20:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

#### docker network ls

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME                    DRIVER    SCOPE
f124d5db3e0b   bridge                  bridge    local
862535ef9371   deluge_default          bridge    local
86bf6736570f   foundryvtt_default      bridge    local
909b8162cdbe   grafana_default         bridge    local
299ce7db89b5   heimdall_default        bridge    local
92a81645a176   host                    host      local
a5e580aa1810   microbin_default        bridge    local
da8d9cb1d3e7   nginx-pm_default        bridge    local
055308848eba   none                    null      local
93afb48bbba2   o-portainer             bridge    local
460a87dcb670   o-security              bridge    local
ea16af5d1414   pihole_default          bridge    local
250440a093d7   portainer_default       bridge    local
971e8873d462   prometheus_default      bridge    local
dcbfb120b9b2   prometheus_monitoring   bridge    local
a482e951879d   prowlarr_default        bridge    local
9ab6f6734815   radarr_default          bridge    local
f6abd6de38d3   sonarr_default          bridge    local
0e062c280f80   spigotmc_default        bridge    local
640505be1145   teamspeak_default       bridge    local
```

after adding portainer to host network **same issue**

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
volumes:
  prometheus_data: {}

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /home/lukas/data/config/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'

    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    network_mode: "host"

    ports:
      - "9090:9090/tcp
```

**docker inspect prometheus (network part)**

```
 "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "f114aceaadadca19fe9da85b04dbce4fc9aedae6d7f91a2bed8b3290d3186e82",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/run/snap.docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "92a81645a17671cf440926ed83cdb6063790dcf2e18813722d96ccc90614ffb3",
                    "EndpointID": "4a4f2cef2556314c2feb526928b24784005a4617583e10813bae06f56d5db8e2",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Prometheus is listing itself at `192.168.2.44` so it appears it's running on a different network than 172.17.0.0/16. Can you add results for `docker inspect` on the Prometheus container and maybe also `docker network ls`?

Comment: The prometheus container is running on the docker server I want to have the metrics from.
I tried adding all you wanted and also tried using the host network for my docker-compose. the issue is still here..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker Compose is creating a network called "prometheus_default" and it's attaching the Prometheus container to that network. You have Docker daemon set to advertise metrics on the `docker0` interface which is generally on the `bridge` default network Docker creates.

On the host where Docker is running, you can verify Docker daemon (-p, to show proccesses) is listening (-l) on the tcp (-t) metrics port number 9323 (-n) via `ss` or `netstat`

```
$ ss -tlpn | grep :9323
LISTEN 0      4096            127.0.0.1:9323       0.0.0.0:*    users:(("dockerd",pid=199176,fd=17))
```

## Option 1

Try adding this config to docker-compose.yaml to add Prometheus to the bridge network

```
version: '3.8'
volumes:
  prometheus_data: {}

services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /home/lukas/data/config/prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
      - prometheus_data:/prometheus
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'

    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    network_mode: bridge

    ports:
      - "9090:9090/tcp
```

while making sure Docker is set to advertise metrics on the default bridge

```
{
   "metrics-addr": "172.17.0.1:9323"
}
```

## Option 2

Change Docker daemon to listen on `prometheus_default` network

```
docker network inspect prometheus_default
[
    {
        "Name": "prometheus_default",
        "Id": "55a40edb42b2f3c1144236a765339e9b1c8dd0542df929430dc07829c5e156d5",
        "Created": "2023-03-31T16:51:48.212544059-04:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "prometheus",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.29.2"
        }
    }
]
```

Set in daemon.json

```
{
   "metrics-addr": "172.19.0.1:9323"
}
```

## Option 3

Allow any network to access Docker metrics (keep in mind much more services will have access to the Docker daemon metrics interface which may or may not be desirable)

```
{
  "metrics-addr": "0.0.0.0:9323"
}
```

Comment: In the end it was my mistake as I forgot a comma in the json file. but this answer also helped me a lot!